# Windows desktop icon guidelines

Tags: icons, windows-os

Are there any *modern* guidelines for how icons should look in desktop Windows?
I'm particularly interested in toolbar icons right now, but I'm hoping for some general icon guidance.

The [Windows Desktop design guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx) looks up-to-date in its broadest sweeps, but when it gets to [specifics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742485(v=vs.85).aspx) it starts making comparisons between Vista and XP styles, which dates it to 2007 or thereabout.

Comment: From a an Enterprise point of view. I belive there should not be any shortcuts on the desktop in the image. User should have whole desktop themselves to place their icons.

Answer (score 3):

It took a few more moments than I had thought, but Microsoft does have an [up-to-date icon style guide for Modern UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn439350.aspx). You can find it not in MSDN, but in a dedicated [Windows Dev Center](https://dev.windows.com/en-us) and its [Design section](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/design/).

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't found that, and it's interesting reading. That said, it's a guide for Windows Store / Windows RT apps, a different beast from Windows desktop apps. It stays far away from crowded little mouseable things like toolbars (not just in the Icons article).

Comment: @hemflit: Windows is moving toward unified UX across all devices and platforms, so "crowded little mousable things" will be considered to be out of style. Take a look at Office Preview for Windows 10: it combined Modern UI with Ribbon tabs and multi-level menus easily. My guess is that they will release a new style guide at Build 2015.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting how, even on the Surface, the [ribbons are actually laid out more like toolbars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5pZ5m1CNcw#t=90) than like the original Office 2007 ribbons.  
I'll take Microsoft's commitment to the new hotness completely to heart as soon as they make Visual Studio finger-friendly.

Comment: Link is broken again :/

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/icons

Comment: Or even this one: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/app-icons-and-logos